# Java HasMap data structure

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I have a file like this (with two types of delimiters "," and ":"):

```
Name,Animal,Spieces,ABB,Score
jane,monkey,mammal,MA,1:2:4
susan,monkey,mammal,MA,11:2b:4
bob,spider,insect,IN,1a:2
```

And classes to store data into objects like this:

```
Class  Spiecies {
    private String spieces;
    private String abb; //unique for each spieces
    private List<Animal>;

   //getters setters
 }

Class Animal {
    private String name;
    private String animal;
    private List<Score>;

    //getters setters
}

Class Score {
    private String points;

    //getters setters
}
```

To retrieve data from file, I want to use HashMap, List ... or some data structure and store data like this:

```
HasMap<String Spieces,HasMap<String Animal, List<Score>>>
```

where data will be stored like this:
`mammal -> [ monkey, jane -> 1:2:4 ],[ monkey, susan -> 11:2b:4 ]` ... etc

Is this correct to store data like this? And how to put ABB into Map?

Comment: What is your definition of "correct"? And why don't you use a `Map<String, Animal>` inside `Spieces` class ?

Comment: "And how to put ABB into Map?" - Seems as you don't have to. If `spieces` values and `abb` values have a 1:1 relation, you could make a lookup to get spieces string from any abb string, then use that result to access the map.

Comment: I want to do some search on data. And I need to retrieve spieces as well.

Comment: Have you thought about an in-mem database, so you can use SQL (and all the stuff that comes with it like joins, filters etc.) ?

Comment: Yes, but I have to do it without DB. If I used DB, how to populate it correctly with these data?

Comment: Well, if you are not allowed to use one, then the question how to populate it is superfluent. Modelling the needed datastructure all with Maps will be pretty tedious, though.

Comment: I asked how to do it in DB, because I am curious how to. I am new to Java, so I am learning and looking for advices. What to use then if not HasMaps? Thanks

Comment: Or is it OK, if I make hashMap like this? Map<String Spieces, List<Score>> and data in Score will not be unique? Like this: [ jane,monkey, 10], [jane,monkey, 2 ] ... etc

Comment: I see. In a DB you would have Tables with certain columns. You then can add all that data using key-columns and later join them as needed. You can construct search statements in SQL like "give me a distinct list of all mammal's names with a score > 5" ... That's not so easy to do with a convoluted "Map in a Map in a Map" - structure ...

Comment: Well, if I had to put data into DB, I was thinking to put them to POJO's first. But well, you are right, I could just do straight inserts while reading file. Actually, I need to work only with spieces (mammal, insect ... ) and scores, but maybe later I will need to use another data. Solution with Maps I suggested seems to me a bit difficult, so that's why I am asking what is the best approach and what structure to use. Or do it completely differently?

Comment: There's "Species" and "Spices", but no "Spieces" that I'm aware of.

Comment: thanks for the correction,but I am not english native speaker. But that is not the point ... The point is, that people who are seeking here for help, and especially the newbies, they don't know, how to ask or what to do. maybe sometimes they sound stupid, or you may thing they want whole solution from you. In my case, I was just seeking for advice after lots of searching I have done and could not find the solution. So sometimes it would be nice just to say: What you are suggesting is wrong, you could do it this way ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use following data structure to simplify

```
Map<String,List<Animal>> map=new HashMap<>();
```

Where 
**Key in Map** => (String spieces) + (String abb)  // Since both combination is unique.

**Value in Map** => List of All animals // give you all animal details based on Spieces + abb combination